# public dictionary in todictionary method

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I am trying to access the dictionary created in the `todictionary` method in other procedures.

This is what I'd like but I'm getting a compile error.

```
Public dctOPT As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)

 Sub Get_RTD_OPT()

        Dim lstOPT = From C In DATA.CHAINs, O In DATA.OPTIONs, U In DATA.UDLies
                     Where C.CONTRACT = O.CONTRACT And O.UDLY_SYM = U.UDLY_SYM
                     Select C.ID, C.P_C, C.STRIKE, C.CONTRACT,
                        O.OPT_EXCHANGE, O.OPT_EXPIRY, O.OPT_SEC_TYPE, O.SYM,
                         U.CURRENCY

        dctOPT = lstOPT.ToDictionary(Function(Z) Z.ID)

end sub
```

This compiles, but then I can't access `dctOPT` in other procedures.

```
dim dctOPT = lstOPT.ToDictionary(Function(Z) Z.ID)
```

Do i need to copy `dctOPT` into another public dictionary or is there a simpler method? Any suggestions please?

Comment: It sounds like the type of `Z.ID` isn't `Integer`.

Comment: Its defined as ``int`` in the datatable, and if I change the public declaration to ``(of string,object)`` I still get a compile error. Is this something to do with anonymous types?

Comment: Try doing `Dim dctOPT = lstOPT.ToDictionary(Function(Z) Z.ID)` and then `dctOPT.GetType()` and see what type it is. Otherwise it just doesn't make sense that it works with the `Dim`, but not without. Could it be an unsigned integer?

Comment: sorry dumb question, but if I add ``dctOPT.GetType()`` and then run the code how do I get the value? placing a break point on the line and holding the mouse over the line doesn't give a result

Comment: Assign it to a variable and add a watch. Do a `Debug.Print`. Heaps of ways.

Comment: debug.print can't convert type type to string. ``Dim S As Type = dctOPT.GetType()`` returns a long string which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please paste the long string that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: +  S {Name = "Dictionary`2" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],.....

its too long by 531 characters. That's the value of S.

The Type of S is System.Type{System.RuntimeType}

Comment: OK, That makes sense. Try `dctOPT = lstOPT.ToDictionary(Function(Z) Z.ID, Function(Z) CType(Z, Object))`.

Comment: tks, glad it makes sense to you! code now compiles but I get another cast error converting a date to a string. ``ContractInfo.expiry = dctOPT(key).OPT_EXPIRY.ToString("yyyyMMdd")``  Additional information: Conversion from string "yyyyMMdd" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
should public dctOPT be of type string,object instead of ``Public dctOPT As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)``

Comment: You need to ask a new question. Make sure you read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. If you post the link back here I'll take a look.

Comment: tks i'll see if I can find a solution first. If you have free time can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123392/sum-multiple-columns-with-filter/35123952#35123952
I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
Public dctOPT As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)

Sub Get_RTD_OPT()

    Dim lstOPT =
        From C In DATA.CHAINs, O In DATA.OPTIONs, U In DATA.UDLies
        Where C.CONTRACT = O.CONTRACT And O.UDLY_SYM = U.UDLY_SYM
        Select C.ID, C.P_C, C.STRIKE, C.CONTRACT,
           O.OPT_EXCHANGE, O.OPT_EXPIRY, O.OPT_SEC_TYPE, O.SYM,
            U.CURRENCY

    dctOPT = lstOPT.ToDictionary(Function(Z) Z.ID, Function(Z) CType(Z, Object))

End Sub
```

Without the `Function(Z) CType(Z, Object)` the type of the dictionary being created was `Dictionary(Of Integer, <anonymous>)` and that cannot be directly assigned to `Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)`. The cast correctly generates a dictionary of the right type.

Comment: tks, I'll see how to fix the other cast problem, but this gets me rolling again